# Adding data to a data table from textbox user input

Tags: vb.net

When I run the project I add values into my textboxes that I want to go into the datatable but it doesn't have the newly inputted data from the textboxes or the new row when I check it out. Anyone know what I'm missing that puts in the data into my datatable? this is my sample code:

```
  Dim lineTable As Data.DataTable = New Data.DataTable("NAFTALineItems")

    lineTable.Columns.Add("NAFTAID")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("NAFTALineID")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("BoxQuantity")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("Weight")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("PartNumber")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("PartDescription")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("QuantityShipped")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("UnitPrice")
    lineTable.Columns.Add("TotalPrice")

    Dim lineRow As DataRow = lineTable.NewRow()
    lineRow("NAFTAID") = txtNaftaID.Text
    lineRow("NAFTALineID") = txtLineID.Text
    lineRow("BoxQuantity") = txtQuantity.Text
    lineRow("Weight") = txtWeight.Text
    lineRow("PartNumber") = txtPartNumber.Text
    lineRow("PartDescription") = txtPartDescription.Text
    lineRow("QuantityShipped") = txtQtyShipped.Text
    lineRow("UnitPrice") = txtPrice.Text
    lineRow("TotalPrice") = txtQtyShipped.Text * txtPrice.Text
```

Comment: I don't see any linetable.rows.add(lineRow).

Comment: You should turn on Option Strict - you are doing math on *strings*.  What does `it doesn't have the newly inputted data from the textboxes or the new row when I check it out` mean?  Did you add the row to the DataTable?  Did you update the db?  none of that is shown

Comment: @Plutonix I mean that when I run the program I put in info into the textboxes and then I go into debug mode to check the linetable to see if the data I put in the textboxes got put into the linetable and they didn't. Looks like I need to add a row to the datatable, I thought linetable.NewRow() does that.

Comment: NewRow creates a new row with the proper col names and data types thats all.  You need to add the row to the rows collection and then update the DB.  Its also a bad idea to save things like totals (quan * price) because it is very easily calculated (the DT wll even do it for you) and because it makes for one more thing to update when one of the components change